# Avro Definition for Custom Aggregator

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, avro

I have a code where I am aggregating the data from Kafka stream via:

```
StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
    streamsBuilder.table(AppConfigs.topicName,
        Consumed.with(AppSerdes.String(), AppSerdes.Employee()))
        .groupBy((k, v) -> KeyValue.pair(v.getDepartment(), v), Grouped.with(AppSerdes.String(), AppSerdes.Employee()))
        .aggregate(
            //Initializer
            
            //Adder
            
            //Subtractor
            
            //Serializer
            Materialized.<String, DepartmentAggregate, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(
                AppConfigs.stateStoreName).withValueSerde(AppSerdes.DepartmentAggregate())
        )
```

I have written the custom Json Serdes for "DepartmentAggregate" as

```
public class AppSerdes extends Serdes {    

static final class DepartmentAggSerde extends WrapperSerde<DepartmentAggregate> {
    DepartmentAggSerde() {
        super(new JsonSerializer<>(), new JsonDeserializer<>());
    }
}

public static Serde<DepartmentAggregate> DepartmentAggregate() {
    DepartmentAggSerde serde = new DepartmentAggSerde();

    Map<String, Object> serdeConfigs = new HashMap<>();
    serdeConfigs.put(JsonDeserializer.VALUE_CLASS_NAME_CONFIG, DepartmentAggregate.class);
    serde.configure(serdeConfigs, false);

    return serde;
}
```

Now I have a requirement where instead of Json, I have to write the same custome logic for Avro Aggregator(Basically, collect values in a list based on id's). Can someone please help with the custom Avro Aggregator code?

Comment: What issues are you having replacing `super(new JsonSerializer<>(), new JsonDeserializer<>());` with respective Avro (de)serializer classes?

Comment: @OneCricketeer The thing is, I am not sure how to write the custom Avro Serdes for my Aggregator. Are you suggesting me to simply replace the code in "super" with "AvroSerializer/Deserializer"? i.e
"super(new JsonSerializer<>(), new JsonDeserializer<>());" changes to "super(new AvroSerializer<>(), new AvroDeserializer<>());"

Comment: That would be start, yes. Then remove/replace the json properties in serdeConfigs. Then if you have specific Avro types that map very closely to your json pojos, nothing else should need changing (without seeing your actual data, or schemas, it's hard to help further)